# Dynamic multi-domain forwarding on a simple hosting account?

Tags: ruby, http, node.js, rack, forwarding

My need to host a few very simple static sites on DropBox has led me to this 'exercise'.
It is probably right between serverfault and stackoverflow, but I'd say it's more programmatically.

I would like to set up a service (similar in look and feel to wasitup.com) that forwards and masks domain for anyone. This will be free, so I am looking for a quick and cheap way to do this.

In the end, my domain cute.domain.com is pointing to my server; the server is delivering a very simple frame with the link to the real content in it, something like http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2818368/test.com/index.html

This alone would be easy, just use .htaccess, nginx or Apache modules. But I would like to be able to that **dynamically** so that everyone can simple fill a few form fields and - presto - has it's own masquerading going.

**I dream of something like a bare ruby/rack or sinatra solution that answers all the requests, checks if the hostname in the request is in a file or even in memory hash table/sqlite db and then replies with the small frame code that includes the link to the destination.**

Answer (score 0):

Why not just install Webmin or some other control panel that already does this?

Comment: The visitors should be able to self service the entries in the forwarding hash. I guess this doesn't work with Webmin et al.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood your requirements. Perhaps what you want is a simple script that writes to the appropriate config file and restarts Apache...

Comment: I guess this would be too expensive - there must be a simply way like just having a nodes servers listening on port 80 and just reply with a little bit of html and a customized frame. or something.

Comment: Actually, using Apache rewrites would be cheaper, because no application server would have to get involved.

Comment: If you *do* need an application server, though, I suspect Node.js would be a good choice (but I've never used it, so take that for what it's worth).